# Перезаписать данные в таблице БД

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Есть таблица в БД с 10к записями. Эти данные берутся со стороннего ресурса и периодически обновляются.
Так вот вопрос: как правильно обновить данные в таблице, если каждый раз приходит разное количество записей?
То больше, то меньше.
Пока что я смотрю в сторону TRUNCATE TABLE, но подозреваю, что это неверное решение.

Comment: А какой % записей собственно меняется при обновлении ? И если сторонних ресурсов несколько вы же одновременно все данные не можете обновить, они небось по одному ресурсу приходят и очищать всю таблицу (по всем ресурсам) перед загрузкой явно избыточно, вдруг какой то из ресурсов окажется временно не доступным, а вы данные уже стерли

Comment: % записей на изменение, думаю, в районе 20%, но точных данных по этому поводу нет. Теоретически изменения могут быть и в 100% записях.

Comment: но я так понимаю вам все равно приходится проверить или попытаться обновить каждую запись, вы же заранее не знаете что именно изменилось. И для вас главное после всего удалить те, которых не было во внешнем источнике в момент обновления, так ? И как вообще идет обновление, скопом по всем ресурсам и гарантируется что они все доступны или по одному. И что делать с записями если какой то ресурс оказался не доступен на момент обновления ?

Comment: Я думал обновлять всё скопом, без дополнительных проверок, чтобы экономить время выполнения скрипта. Да, главное удалить лишние записи. Обновления идут с одного ресурса. Про возможную недоступность ресурса еще не не думал. Но думаю, можно перед стартом скрипта прикрутить какую-то проверку на доступность.

Comment: Судя по тому, что TRUNCATE Вас не пугает, связей у этой таблицы нет. Если так - то рекомендую делать импорт в новую таблицу, и если он прошёл удачно (и ресурс был доступен, и данные с него получены корректные и без проблем импортировались), то просто подменять старую таблицу на новую (два переименования, делов-то...). При этом старые таблицы не удалять сразу (а ну как что не то!), а хранить по крайней мере пару предпоследних версий.

Comment: Да, связей нет. Спасибо, интересный вариант!

Comment: Или вести колонку version. при обновлении таблицы выполнять `insert on duplicate key update ` и писать новую версию (на 1 большую чем при предыдущем обновлении или например сегодняшнюю дату). По завершении, если с получением данных с ресурса было все ок, удалять записи с версией меньше текущей (или не удалять, а оставлять для истории например)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Буду пробовать.